# Why does Order Matter for the Equality Operator ("==") in Bash with Double Brackets ("[[")?

Tags: bash

The following command works as I'd expected, printing out "huh?":

```
$ if [[ "odd behavior" == *odd* ]]; then echo "huh?"; fi
huh?
```

But if I switch the order of the operands, nothing is printed out:

```
$ if [[ *odd* == "odd behavior" ]]; then echo "huh?"; fi
<no output>
```

This seems counter-intuitive to me. Can somebody explain why the behavior is different?

Comment: Take a look: `help [[`

Comment: `*odd*` is an operation, `"odd behavior"` is simply a literal. In the second, the operation is first performed and evaluated against "odd behavior" which is likely to be `false`.  Whereas, in the first, the operation evaluated to a successful non-zero result and when compared to a literal (not by value but simply non-null during type conversion) resulted in 1 == 1 which is `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right argument is treated specially, it can be a wildcard pattern, but the left argument can't be. From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in Pattern Matching, as if the extglob shell option were enabled. The ‘=’ operator is identical to ‘==’. If the nocasematch shell option (see the description of shopt in The Shopt Builtin) is enabled, the match is performed without regard to the case of alphabetic characters. The return value is 0 if the string matches (‘==’) or does not match (‘!=’)the pattern, and 1 otherwise. Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string.

Comment: Thank you, great concise answer!

I didn't realize the left operands would not be treated in the same way as the right operands (i.e. as a pattern). Good to know!

Comment: To get more concise, the text in quotes is a literal string while the `*` is a regex. `"odd behavior"` is contained within the set defined by `*odd*`, BUT everything in the set defined by `*odd*` is not contained within `"odd behavior"`.

Comment: @KipK It has nothing to do with quotes. You can only put the wildcard on the right.

Comment: But if you put it in quotes on the right, then it's not a wildcard at all. If you're just doing ordinary comparison, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: I know that, I am talking about the literal interpretation of the two values, not just how `[[ ]]` works.